Calculate the uncertainty from the geometric mean and geometric standard deviation
I'm working on a database that provide for each entry a geometric mean value as well as a geometric standard deviation. I would like to transform this value into an approximate relative uncertainty. For example, if I had the artihmetic mean and the arithmetic standard deviation I would calculate the uncertainty as $u=\frac{\sigma }{\overline{x}}$. I thoroughly searched the web and the forum to find some starting points but I couldn't find any.
How would you calculate/approximate the relative uncertainty from these two values?
edit
As @Henry pointed in the comment sections, a formula for calculating the coefficient of variation exists. But there's something I don't get with the formula $u=\sqrt{e^{s^{2}}-1}$. If I understand correctly, $s=1$ is the neutral standard deviation for geometric statistics, meaning that there should be 0 uncertainty. But the actual uncertainty is evaluated to be $u=1.31$, so more than twice the mean value. There's clearly something I'm not getting correctly.
Edit 2
By geometric standard deviation, I mean this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_standard_deviation
My problem is maybe to estimate the standard deviation from this geometric standard deviation.

What you are calling "relative uncertainty" has many other names including "coefficient of variation".

Thanks for your comment, I updated the original question so it better reflects my problem

The standard deviation divided by the mean has many names including "coefficient of variation".
If you take the particular example of a log-normal distributed random variable $Y$, i.e. where $\log_e(Y)=X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then

the expectation of $Y$ is $e^{\mu +\frac{\sigma^2}2}$ and the variance of $Y$ is $\left(e^{\sigma^2}-1\right)\,e^{2\mu +\sigma^2}$, so the standard deviation of $Y$ is $\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2}-1}\,e^{\mu +\frac{\sigma^2}2}$ and the coefficient of variation is $\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2}-1}$.  The coefficient of variation is $0$ when $\sigma^2=0$ and will be greater than $1$ when $\sigma^2>0.69315$; a large coefficient of variation should not be a surprise as a log-normal distribution can be heavily right-skewed.

the geometric mean of $Y$ is $e^{\mathbb E[X]}=e^\mu$, as is the median of $Y$.  I do not know how you are defining "geometric standard deviation", but perhaps you intend $\sqrt{e^{\sigma^2}}= e^{\frac12\sigma^2}$ or perhaps you intend the different $e^{\sigma}$.



Thanks and sorry for the long response time. By the geometric standard deviation, I mean this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_standard_deviation

@ThibaultAbry That definition of geometric standard deviation looks to me like $e^\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of $\log_e(Y)$.  Note that it is not the square root of what you would call the geometric variance.
